# File Properties in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, file-management

I am running Windows 10 (professional edition).  I have many .mp3 files and many .aac files.  When I go to the details tab in the File Properties window for a .mp3 file, there are entries for various properties such as "title", "artist", "album", etc.  When I do the same for a .aac file, those properties are missing.  As shown:[image]

I would like all the same properties to appear for the .aac files as or the .mp3 files.  How do I make this happen?

Additional info:  Using third-party software, I have no trouble assigning Title, Album, Artist, etc. to the .aac files.  However, when I look at these files in the Windows File Manager, the entries in those columns are blank.  When I assign these properties to a .mp3 file in exactly the same way using exactly the same software, the corresponding entries in File Manager appear exactly as they should.

Comment: MP3 files have a standard tag format, AAC files don't.

Comment: You would have to convert the aac files to mp3 (or some other format supporting standard tags).

Comment: @ChanganAuto :  Thanks.  I didn't know this.

Comment: @DavidPostill :  Thanks.  I hadn't known this.  (If either you or ChanganAuto had made this an answer I'd have accepted it, but since you didn't, I wanted to at least let you know that I read and appreciated your comments.  And I repeated the comment so I could tag both of you.)

Answer (score 0):

Converting files to get properties sounds like an low practical way to get what you expect. Take a look at [File Metadata](https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta) and set the default mp3 to other file types not supported by Windows.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, MP3 files (can) have tags. There’s multiple formats (ID3v1, ID3v2, APE), it’s chaos, but possible. That’s what Windows displays here. IIRC Windows always writes ID3v2 tags when you change something.

It is unclear what your .aac files actually are. If they’re raw AAC streams (not technically raw but MPEG ADTS), then it is indeed correct that no tagging is possible on these. However, AAC audio is usually packaged in an MP4 container (commonly named .m4a, but .mp4 is also possible), which does support tags.

You can check the actual type using *ffmpeg*:

```
ffprobe the_file.aac
```

or, if `ffprobe` is not available:

```
ffmpeg -i the_file.aac
```

This will produce an error message but still report all relevant information. It could look like this:

```
ffprobe version n5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: <snip>
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'the_file.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 38 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 35 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

or like this, for a “raw” file:

```
[aac @ 0x557e0f0c6940] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, aac, from 'the_file.aac':
  Duration: 00:00:02.69, bitrate: 34 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 34 kb/s
```

You can also use *ffmpeg* to convert these (losslessly!) to .m4a files:

```
ffmpeg -i the_file.aac -c:a copy the_file.m4a
```

You can then add tags.